# Should i have to enable cors for ios client?

Tags: ios, .net, ajax, api, cors

I have api application which was built in .net api 2.now i want to use this api service from ios app.so should i have to enable cors for ios app to use my api service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is not a browser-based client then no you should not need to enable CORS.

CORS rules only apply to ajax requests made from a browser.